# La resta y división no funcionan como espero

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio que encontré en Internet. El usuario puede ingresar uno, dos o más datos para calcular la suma, resta, multiplicación y división al final de la función.

El tema es que la resta y la división no están funcionando como espero.

Al principio intenté hacer lo mismo que hago con la suma y la multiplicación (estaban incluidos en el mismo `for of`), pero tampoco funcionaban, así que llegué a la conclusión de que si restamos y dividimos por el primer número de la matriz de números que nos pasa el usuario podría tener mejores resultados, pero no parece que así sea.

Lo que quiero saber es qué estoy haciendo mal con la resta y la división y qué forma hay de lograr lo que quiero hacer (que los números introducidos por el usuario se sumen, resten, multipliquen y dividan y que cada uno se muestre por consola).

Éste es el código:

```js
alert('¡Bienvenido a su calculadora! Se calculará la suma, resta, multiplicación y división de los valores que ingrese.\nSi quiere calcular la raíz cuadrada de un número, ingrese un solo valor numerérico.\n\nPodrá visualizar los resultados en consola.');

let data;
let acc = [];
let sum = 0, subtract = 0, multiplication = 1, division = 1;

const getValues = () => {
    data = Number(prompt(`Ingrese sus valores numéricos.`));
    if (isNaN(data)) {
        alert(`ERROR: Ingrese únicamente valores numéricos!`);
        getValues();
    } else {
        acc.push(data);
        let addMoreValues = confirm(`¿Quiere agregar más valores?`);
        if (addMoreValues === true) {
            getValues();
        } else {
            calculate();
        }
    }
}

const calculate = () => {
    if (acc.length === 1) {
        console.log(`La raíz cuadrada de ${acc[acc.length - 1]} es ${Math.sqrt(acc[acc.length - 1]).toFixed(2)}`);
    } else {
        for (let i of acc) {
            sum += i;
            multiplication *= i;
        }
        let firstNumber = acc[0];
        for (let i = 1; i < acc.length; i++) {
            subtract = firstNumber -= acc[i];
            division = firstNumber /= acc[i];
        }
        console.log(`Sus valores introducidos son: ${acc.join(', ')}.\n\nLa suma de sus valores es: ${sum}\nLa resta de sus números es: ${subtract}\nLa multiplicación de sus números es: ${multiplication}\nLa división de sus números es: ${division}\n`);
        alert(`Sus resultados han sido mostrados por consola.`);
    }
    repeatProcess();
}

const repeatProcess = () => {
    let echo = confirm(`¿Quiere volver a utilizar la calculadora?`);
    if (echo === true) {
        acc = [];
        getValues();
    } else {
        alert(`¡Gracias por utilizar la calculadora!`);
    }
}

getValues();
```

EDIT: Espero que la función `calculate();` funcione sin importar cuántos valores ingrese el usuario, pero al ingresar 3 o más, la resta y la división arrojan resultados que no logro comprender de dónde provienen, lo que quiero es lo siguiente: Si ingreso 10, 2 y 3 como primer, segundo y tercer valor, entonces: 10 - 2 - 3 = 5
Resultado esperado: 5
Resultado obtenido: 1... Y pasa lo mismo con la división.

Comment: No olvides mostrar en tu pregunta cuál es el resultado esperado y el obtenido.

Comment: Para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). En él debes incluir qué datos de entrada debemos proporcionar para reproducir tu problema, el valor erróneo generado y el valor correcto esperado. Yo he hecho un par de pruebas (sin revisar cómo funciona el código e introduciendo solo dos números) y parece que funciona correctamente.

Comment: Error encontrado, redactando respuesta.

Comment: Espero que la función calculate(); funcione sin importar cuántos valores ingrese el usuario, pero al ingresar 3 o más, la resta y la división arrojan resultados que no logro comprender de dónde provienen, lo que quiero es lo siguiente:
Si ingreso 10, 2 y 3 como primer, segundo y tercer valor, entonces:
10 - 2 - 3 = 5
Resultado esperado: 5
Resultado obtenido: 1...
Y lo mismo con la división.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error en tu código está en las siguientes líneas:

```
for (let i = 1; i < acc.length; i++) {
    subtract = firstNumber -= acc[i];
    division = firstNumber /= acc[i];
}
```

En cada línea estás actualizando el valor de `firstNumber`, por lo que la resta afectará a la división, y la división afectará a la resta y, en general, el valor de `firstNumber` se perderá tras la primera iteración y en cada operación tendrá un valor diferente.

Es decir, esto sería lo que se ejecutaría realmente:

```
for (let i = 1; i < acc.length; i++) {
    firstNumber -= acc[i];
    subtract = firstNumber;
    firstNumber /= acc[i];
    division = firstNumber;
}
```

No es lo que esperabas, ¿verdad?.

Una forma de solucionar este problema sería el siguiente:

```
subtract = division = acc[0];
for (let i = 1; i < acc.length; i++) {
    subtract -= acc[i];
    division /= acc[i];
}
```

La primera línea sería equivalente a:

```
subtract = acc[0];
division = acc[0];
```

Aquí lo tienes en funcionamiento:

```js
alert('¡Bienvenido a su calculadora! Se calculará la suma, resta, multiplicación y división de los valores que ingrese.\nSi quiere calcular la raíz cuadrada de un número, ingrese un solo valor numerérico.\n\nPodrá visualizar los resultados en consola.');

let data;
let acc = [];
let sum = 0, subtract = 0, multiplication = 1, division = 1;

const getValues = () => {
    data = Number(prompt(`Ingrese sus valores numéricos.`));
    if (isNaN(data)) {
        alert(`ERROR: Ingrese únicamente valores numéricos!`);
        getValues();
    } else {
        acc.push(data);
        let addMoreValues = confirm(`¿Quiere agregar más valores?`);
        if (addMoreValues === true) {
            getValues();
        } else {
            calculate();
        }
    }
}

const calculate = () => {
    if (acc.length === 1) {
        console.log(`La raíz cuadrada de ${acc[acc.length - 1]} es ${Math.sqrt(acc[acc.length - 1]).toFixed(2)}`);
    } else {
        for (let i of acc) {
            sum += i;
            multiplication *= i;
        }
        let subtract = division = acc[0];
        for (let i = 1; i < acc.length; i++) {
            subtract -= acc[i];
            division /= acc[i];
        }
        console.log(`Sus valores introducidos son: ${acc.join(', ')}.\n\nLa suma de sus valores es: ${sum}\nLa resta de sus números es: ${subtract}\nLa multiplicación de sus números es: ${multiplication}\nLa división de sus números es: ${division}\n`);
        alert(`Sus resultados han sido mostrados por consola.`);
    }
    repeatProcess();
}

const repeatProcess = () => {
    let echo = confirm(`¿Quiere volver a utilizar la calculadora?`);
    if (echo === true) {
        acc = [];
        getValues();
    } else {
        alert(`¡Gracias por utilizar la calculadora!`);
    }
}

getValues();
```

Comment: Gracias Oscar! Comprendo, no entendía por qué me arrojaba esos resultados pero ahora, gracias a tu explicación, sé por qué, y también entendí tu corrección a la perfección!

Muchas gracias, un saludo!

Comment: ¡Un placer ser de ayuda! Te aconsejo que, por claridad de lectura del código, no realices más de una operación anidada y que, a ser posible, solo las uses en asignaciones. Cosas como `var1 += var2 *= var3;` pueden volverte loco tanto para entender lo que hacen como para depurar su comportamiento.